# kafka consumer group getting duplicate message in kafka-node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to setup the Kafka queue for my application in node. I have 3 consumer in a consumer group and which is subscribed to single topic but when a producer sends messages to a topic having 3 partition, the consumer group receiving duplicate messages 
e.g consumer1 reads from partition1 and fetches messages and consumer2 also reads from same partition and fetches same message.

i have given the link to git repository which has all the executable code. i am not able to find is it setup problem? or node package problem.

options provided to create a consumer group is below

```
    consumerOptions = {
          'kafkahost:'localhost:9092',
          groupId: groupName,
          autoCommit: true,
          autoCommitIntervalMs: 1000,
          sessionTimeout: 15000,
          fetchMaxBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB
          protocol: ['roundrobin'],
          fromOffset: 'earliest'
    };

    var consumer = new kafka.ConsumerGroup(Object.assign({ id: 'consumer1' }, consumerOptions), topicName);
```

plz refer this link for executable code, broker config and zookeeper config
https://github.com/Raghavendralacharya/kafka-node.git

Answer (score 0):

Try out to change the `fromOffset` config to:

```
fromOffset: 'latest'
```

Comment: if i am right earliest is to pick all the data from where last commit happened. latest is to pick data that has been pushed to kafka after consumer came up. But my problem is in both case the same message is read by multiple consumer in consumer group.